# How to zoom in AR

Tags: google-project-tango

I am using Unity and AR learning and I am trying to zoom in the visual so that I can select more distant points in space better.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I noticed that the measure-it app from google does not support zooming.

The answer provided by gtp works wonderfully.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In a Tango Unity project, you can make the camera view zoom by modifying the UVs on the camera feed using [`VideoOverlayProvider.SetARScreenUVs`](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers/VideoOverlayProvider.cs#L197) and adjusting your camera frustum in a corresponding way.

As an example, start from the [Unity Tango Examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity), and modify [TangoARScreen.cs](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoARScreen.cs) so that in `_SetRenderAndCamera`, the uvs are adjusted before they are passed to `_MaterialUpdateForIntrinsics` (which in turn passes these through to `VideoOverlayProvider.SetARScreenUVs`).  This is the snippet I added before the call to `_MaterialUpdateForIntrinsics` to verify that this works in practice:

```
float width = 1.0f - 2.0f * m_uOffset;
float height = 1.0f - 2.0f * m_vOffset;

float newWidth = width / m_zoomLevel;
float newHeight = height / m_zoomLevel;

m_uOffset = (1.0f - newWidth) / 2.0f;
m_vOffset = (1.0f - newHeight) / 2.0f;
```

If you build and run the AugmentedReality scene on your Tango device with these changes you should see the same pin-placement sample, but with the scene zoomed according to m_zoomLevel.